# Scala case having 22 fields but having issue with play-json in scala 2.11.5

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

With Scala 2.11, we are allowed to have more then 22 fields in a case class right??

```
case class SomeResponse(
                                     var compositeKey: String,
                                     var id1: String,
                                     var id2: String,
                                     var firstName: String,
                                     var lastName: String,
                                     var email: String,
                                     var email2: String,
                                     var birth: Long,
                                     var gender: String,
                                     var phone: Phone,
                                     var city: String,
                                     var zip: String,
                                     var carriage: Boolean,
                                     var carriage2: Boolean,
                                     var fooLong: Long,
                                     var fooLong2: Long,
                                     var suspended: Boolean,
                                     var foo: Foo,
                                     var address: String,
                                     var suite: String,
                                     var state: String,
                                     var instructions: String)

implicit val formatSomeResponse = Json.format[SomeResponse]
```

Well the above is a case class which has exactly 22 fields with the play-json format, now when I compile, I get this error:

```
SomeFile.scala:126: value apply is not a member of play.api.libs.functional.FunctionalBuilder[play.api.libs.json.OFormat]#CanBuild22[String,String,String,String,String,String,String,Long,String,com.Phone,String,String,Boolean,Boolean,Long,Long,Boolean,com.Foo,String,String,String,String]
```

And the case class Phone and Foo, each have two fields each.

So, why am I actually facing the issue, it doesn't cross the 22 fields limit or is there something else I did wrong, and I tried it in **scala 2.11.5/2.11.1 -  play-json 2.3**

Update:
Based on answers by James and Phadej

```
  val someResponseFirstFormat: OFormat[(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, Long, String, Phone, String)] =
    ((__ \ "compositeKey").format[String] and
      (__ \ "id1").format[String] and
      (__ \ "id2").format[String] and
      (__ \ "firstName").format[String] and
      (__ \ "lastName").format[String] and
      (__ \ "email").format[String] and
      (__ \ "email2").format[String] and
      (__ \ "birth").format[Long] and
      (__ \ "gender").format[String] and
      (__ \ "phone").format[Phone] and
      (__ \ "city").format[String]).tupled

  val someResponseSecondFormat: OFormat[(String, Boolean, Boolean, Long, Long, Boolean, Foo, String, String, String, String)] =
    ((__ \ "zip").format[String] and
      (__ \ "carriage").format[Boolean] and
      (__ \ "carriage2").format[Boolean] and
      (__ \ "fooLong").format[Long] and
      (__ \ "fooLong2").format[Long] and
      (__ \ "suspended").format[Boolean] and
      (__ \ "foo").format[Foo] and
      (__ \ "address").format[String] and
      (__ \ "suite").format[String] and
      (__ \ "country").format[String] and
      (__ \ "instructions").format[String]).tupled

  implicit val formatSome: Format[SomeResponse] = (
    someResponseFirstFormat and someResponseSecondFormat
    ).apply({
    case ((compositeKey, id1, id2, firstName, lastName, email, email2, birth, gender, phone, city),
    (zip, carriage, carriage2, created, updated, suspended, foo, address, suite, country, instructions)) =>
      SomeResponse(compositeKey, id1, id2, firstName, lastName, email, email2, birth, gender, phone, city, zip, carriage, carriage2, created, updated, suspended, location, address, suite, country, instructions)
  }, huge => ((huge.compositeKey, huge.id1, huge.id2, huge.firstName, huge.lastName, huge.email, huge.email2, huge.birth, huge.gender, huge.phone, huge.city),
    (huge.zip, huge.carriage, huge.carriage2, huge.created, huge.updated, huge.suspended, huge.foo, huge.address, huge.suite, huge.country, huge.instructions)))
```

Comment: Sounds like this is a problem with play-json rather than with scala. At a complete guess, it's possible play still respects the limit if play still has to support scala 2.10?

Comment: Yes, its explained in this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571677/22-fields-limit-in-scala-2-11-play-framework-2-3-case-classes-and-functions , but the thing is I haven't crossed the 'more than 22' limit. So, according to play-json, it needs to be less than 22?

Comment: this must be hell...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can split your `Reads` definition:

```
val fields1to10: Reads[(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J)] = ???
val fields11to20 = ???
val fields21to30 = ???

implicit val hugeCaseClassReads: Reads[HugeCaseClass] = (
  fields1to10 and fields11to20 and fields21to30
) { a, b, c => createHugeCaseClassFromThreeTuples(a, b, c) }
```

---

The reason why "functional syntax" doesn't work for more than 22 fields is because there are intermediate classes defined only up to 22: [FunctionalBuilder](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.functional.FunctionalBuilder)

---

Fully written out for small example it would look like:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

// Let's pretend this is huge:
case class Huge(a: Int, b: String, c: Boolean, d: List[Int])

val fields1to2: Reads[(Int, String)] = (
  (__ \ "a").read[Int] and
  (__ \ "b").read[String]
).tupled

val fields3to4: Reads[(Boolean, List[Int])] = (
  (__ \ "c").read[Boolean] and
  (__ \ "d").read[List[Int]]
).tupled

implicit val hugeCaseClassReads: Reads[Huge] = (
  fields1to2 and fields3to4
) {
  case ((a, b), (c, d)) =>  
    Huge(a, b, c, d)
}
```

And the result of tryint to validate `null`:

```
scala> JsNull.validate[Huge]
res6: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Huge] = JsError(
  List(
    (/b,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray()))),
    (/d,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray()))),
    (/c,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray()))),
    (/a,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray())))))
```

As you can see, all fields are tried.

---

Or you could extend play with even more `CanBuildNN` classes: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.6/framework/src/play-functional/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/functional/Products.scala

---

Yet I'd advice you to group fields in the `SomeResponse` class, for example address related etc. And write `Reads` and `Writes` instances by hand, if the JSON structure is flat and cannot be changed.

Comment: Can you provide a usage example, I tried doing as you have suggested, but can't get a proper answer

Comment: CanBuild22 is already provided on master, CanBuild23 and greater is impossible, because they would require Tuple23 and Function23, which don't exist.

Comment: @JamesRoper can't they be defined by user too? or is there some JVM restrictions?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, maybe they could be. Though that wouldn't help with case classes, as the Scala compiler won't generate the apply/unapply methods on case class companion objects with more than 22 fields, do you'd also have to implement them manually yourself to get the play json macros working.

Comment: @JamesRoper that's why I recommend to group fields, so you don't go over 22 limit or even near it :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I can't change the response json structure cause I have no jurisdiction to do so. As the response is from a third part api. But anyways, for now the issue is tackled.

Comment: @phadej Can I use this way on play.api.libs.json.Format? I got an error "value and is not a member of play.api.libs.json.Format".

Comment: @angelokh, yes. But you have to write both `Reads` (as above) and `Writes` (could be written directly) parts of `Format` by hand.

Comment: @phadej Sorry, I am not quite sure I understand. Can you please give some examples?

Comment: @angelokh you can make `Format[A]` from `Reads[A]` and `Writes[A]` by using `apply` on the Format object: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.5/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Format$

Comment: @phadej I try to combine writes for Huge. But it seems I have to create a json output instead of creating a Huge object. Am I right? Also, if I am already using reads and writes, why do I need to create Format? The reason to use Format is to save time writing Reads and Writes both.

Comment: I don't think this works any more, at least not with `play-json 2.4.3`

Comment: @phadej I can't have this working. Copying and pasting your example in my project I got this error `Error:(19, 4) missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
) {
  ^`

Comment: Hi guys!
I see that it's possible to combine `reads` for big objects, however, I don't see how to combine Writes` or Format
If I have to implement Writes on my own, it doesn't make sense to do such hacks just for reads...

Comment: Does the limitation mean that having a case class with > 22 parameters is a bad design?

Answer (score 14):

To make the example above compile, I had to make the type explicit:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

// Let's pretend this is huge:
case class Huge(a: Int, b: String, c: Boolean, d: List[Int])

object Huge {
  val fields1to2: Reads[(Int, String)] = (
    (__ \ "a").read[Int] and
    (__ \ "b").read[String]
  ).tupled

  val fields3to4: Reads[(Boolean, List[Int])] = (
    (__ \ "c").read[Boolean] and
    (__ \ "d").read[List[Int]]
  ).tupled

  val f: ((Int, String), (Boolean, List[Int])) => Huge = {
    case ((a, b), (c, d)) => Huge(a, b, c, d)
  }

  implicit val hugeCaseClassReads: Reads[Huge] = (
    fields1to2 and fields3to4
  ) { f }

}
```

Comment: Could you give a full example for a OWrites/OFormat? There is one [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3174) but it does not compile on 2.5.9+