# Scala case has 22 fields but having issue with play-json in scala 2.11.5

Tags: json, scala, play-json

We are currently using scala 2.11.5 and 1 of my class has 22 fields.

```
  case class CreateTransactionRequest(name: Option[String],
                                  balance: Option[BigDecimal],
                                  amount: BigDecimal,
                                  currency: String,
                                  dueDate: Option[DateTime],
                                  orderDate: DateTime,
                                  billing: Option[CreateAddressRequest],
                                  shipping: Option[CreateAddressRequest],
                                  status: String,
                                  email: String,
                                  paymentMethod: String,
                                  paymentTerm: Option[String],
                                  deliveryMethod: Option[String],
                                  source: String,
                                  attachments: Option[String],
                                  agent: Option[String],
                                  orders: Option[Set[CreateOrderRequest]],
                                  otherCharges: Option[Seq[CreateTransactionOtherChargeRequest]],
                                  notes: Option[Seq[CreateNoteRequest]],
                                  subscribers: Option[Seq[String]],
                                  trackingId: Option[String],
                                  acquisition: Option[String])

implicit val readsCreateTransactionRequest: Reads[CreateTransactionRequest] = Json.reads[CreateTransactionRequest]
```

Upon looking around I came across of a solution and applied it

```
val fields1to12: Reads[(Option[String], Option[BigDecimal], BigDecimal, String, Option[DateTime], DateTime, Option[CreateAddressRequest], Option[CreateAddressRequest], String, String, String, Option[String])] = (
    (__ \ "name").read[Option[String]] and
    (__ \ "balance").read[Option[BigDecimal]] and
    (__ \ "amount").read[BigDecimal] and
    (__ \ "currency").read[String] and
    (__ \ "dueDate").read[Option[DateTime]] and
    (__ \ "orderDate").read[DateTime] and
    (__ \ "billing").read[Option[CreateAddressRequest]] and
    (__ \ "shipping").read[Option[CreateAddressRequest]] and
    (__ \ "status").read[String] and
    (__ \ "email").read[String] and
    (__ \ "paymentMethod").read[String] and
    (__ \ "paymentTerm").read[Option[String]]
  ).tupled

  val fields13to22: Reads[(Option[String], String, Option[String], Option[String], Option[Set[CreateOrderRequest]], Option[Seq[CreateTransactionOtherChargeRequest]], Option[Seq[CreateNoteRequest]], Option[Seq[String]], Option[String], Option[String])] = (
    (__ \ "deliveryMethod").read[Option[String]] and
    (__ \ "source").read[String] and
    (__ \ "attachments").read[Option[String]] and
    (__ \ "agent").read[Option[String]] and
    (__ \ "orders").read[Option[Set[CreateOrderRequest]]] and
    (__ \ "otherCharges").read[Option[Seq[CreateTransactionOtherChargeRequest]]] and
    (__ \ "notes").read[Option[Seq[CreateNoteRequest]]] and
    (__ \ "subscribers").read[Option[Seq[String]]] and
    (__ \ "trackingId").read[Option[String]] and
    (__ \ "acquisition").read[Option[String]]
  ).tupled

implicit val readsCreateTransactionRequest: Reads[CreateTransactionRequest] = (fields1to12, fields13to22) {
    case((name, balance, amount, currency, dueDate, orderDate, billing, shipping, status, email, paymentMethod, paymentTerm), (deliveryMethod, source, attachments, agent, orders, otherCharges, notes, subscribers, trackingId, acquisition)) => 
    CreateTransactionRequest(name, balance, amount, currency, dueDate, orderDate, billing, shipping, status, email, paymentMethod, paymentTerm, deliveryMethod, source, attachments, agent, orders, otherCharges, notes, subscribers, trackingId, acquisition)
  }
```

I am sure that I have followed and tried from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167971/scala-case-having-22-fields-but-having-issue-with-play-json-in-scala-2-11-5]). Unfortunately, it is not working and I am still having errors

Can someone suggest some other way to split the 22 fields upon `Read`?

Comment: Create a `case class` that groups some of the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the full code is not provided, i can see some problem in the code. At first, you are writing below code:

```
(__ \ "billing").read[Option[CreateAddressRequest]]
```

Here, **CreateAddressRequest** is not a primitive type. So, you need to write an implicit Writes for **CreateAddressRequest**.

Then, your maximum fields of the case class are optional. play can't manually serialize/deserialize optional fields. So, you need to have below code.

```
implicit def optionFormat[T: Format]: Format[Option[T]] = new Format[Option[T]] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Option[T]] = json.validateOpt[T]

    override def writes(o: Option[T]): JsValue = o match {
      case Some(t) => implicitly[Writes[T]].writes(t)
      case None    => JsNull
    }
  }
```

And, play also can't serialize/deserialize Date fields. You need to write **Writes** of Date also. Below is a sample code for **java.util.Date** Write.

```
implicit object DateFormat extends Format[java.util.Date] {
    val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[java.util.Date] = JsSuccess(format.parse(json.as[String]))
    def writes(date: java.util.Date): JsString = JsString(format.format(date))
  }
```

**A sample has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46109807/4299527) and you can read my article [here](https://medium.com/@setu677/how-to-write-implicit-writes-for-case-class-having-more-than-22-fields-89b4e152610e)**