# How to write implicit Writes for case class having more than 22 fields

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

```
case class Foo(
  _1:Int,_2:Int,_3:Int,_4:Int,_5:Int,
  _21:Int,_22:Int,_23:Int,_24:Int,_25:Int,
  _31:Int,_32:Int,_33:Int,_34:Int,_35:Int,
  _41:Int,_42:Int,_43:Int,_44:Int,_45:Int,
  _51:Int,_52:Int,_53:Int,_54:Int,_55:Int
)
```

For a case class like this, I need to write implicit json de- / serializer.
I tried splitting the fields, and had a JSONFormat. But still I  need implicit OWrited for using Json.obj(). I tried with play-json-extensions also. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried value classes ?

Comment: value classes? sorry. can you please explain me that?

Comment: Please check documentation at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html

Comment: How value class can be used in this example? and how it will solve?

Comment: I don't see how value classes will solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really 3 avenues for you to explore here:

1. Write out each class explicitly yourself (yes, tons of boilerplate.)
2. Do it with Macros or [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).
3. Use someone's library who already did #2.

I like it when someone else does the work for me. So with that in mind, #3 seems like my preferred solution... And what would you know? Someone else did just that: [play-json-derived-codecs](https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-derived-codecs). Since it uses [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), it will be able to handle case classses of arbitrary size, not just those constrained by ProductN (1-22, depending on your version of Scala.)

Comment: +1 for someone else library. You also have [play-json-extensions](https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions) that uses macros to do the work

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve without using [play-json-extensions](https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions). Suppose we have a case class of more than 22 fields like below:

```
case class Foo(
  A: Int,
  B: Option[Int],
  C: String,
  D: Option[String],
  E: Seq[String],
  F: Date
  more fields..
)
```

Now we will split and group the fields into some groups and write formats.

```
val fooFormat1: OFormat[(Int, Option[Int], String)] =
    ((__ \ "A").format[Long]
      ~ (__ \ "B").format[Option[Long]]
      ~ (__ \ "C").format[Option[Long]]).tupled


val fooFormat2: OFormat[(Option[String], Seq[String], Date)] =
    ((__ \ "D").format[Long]
      ~ (__ \ "E").format[Option[Long]]
      ~ (__ \ "F").format[Option[Long]]).tupled
```

And finally merge all the formats into one format.

```
 implicit val fooFormat: Format[Foo] = (fooFormat1 ~ fooFormat2)({
     case ((a, b, c), (d, e, f)) =>
      new Foo(a, b, c, d, e, f)
   }, (foo: Foo) => ((
    foo.A,
    foo.B,
    foo.C
  ), (
      foo.D,
      foo.E,
      foo.F
    )))
```

We need to import function syntax like below:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
```

Now, play can not serialize/deserialize optional and date fields. So, we need to write implicit formats for optional and date fields like below:

```
implicit object DateFormat extends Format[java.util.Date] {
    val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[java.util.Date] = JsSuccess(format.parse(json.as[String]))
    def writes(date: java.util.Date): JsString = JsString(format.format(date))
  }

implicit def optionFormat[T: Format]: Format[Option[T]] = new Format[Option[T]] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Option[T]] = json.validateOpt[T]

    override def writes(o: Option[T]): JsValue = o match {
      case Some(t) => implicitly[Writes[T]].writes(t)
      case None    => JsNull
    }
  }
```

That's all we need to write **Writes** for case classes more than **22** fields.

**You can read my article [here](https://medium.com/@setu677/how-to-write-implicit-writes-for-case-class-having-more-than-22-fields-89b4e152610e)..**

Comment: how to ignore null fields json? case None    => JsNull this returns fields with null