# Scala play!2 create Json formatter for a class in external library

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I use https://github.com/DanielaSfregola/twitter4s and I need to read and parse the User class provided by twitter4s in Json.

So I tried to create the following serializer :

```
object User {
    implicit val twitterUser: OFormat[User] = Json.format[User]
}
```

but this return `No unapply or unapplySeq function found`

How can I create a correct serializer for this external class ?

Comment: not sure, but the fact that User is a case class with 22+ fields may introduce some special problem? https://github.com/DanielaSfregola/twitter4s/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/danielasfregola/twitter4s/entities/User.scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `User` has a LOT of fields (namely more than 22). In scala 2.10, there was a limitation on the number of fields for a case class. This disappeared in 2.11, but not in the `Json.format` macro of Play!, since they have continued support for 2.10.

However, you can use [Json Extra](https://github.com/aparo/play-json-extra), that have a different implementation for macros, and allows you to go further than 22 fields.

If you don't like this (the macro has some limitations, such as not outputing an `OFormat`), you can also split the `User` class in two (or more) classes with less than 22 fields, and build the initial one from those, with a simpler (and safer) implementation for `Format` that what you would have to do, if you did the whole thing by hand.

You can also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167971/scala-case-having-22-fields-but-having-issue-with-play-json-in-scala-2-11-5), for further explanations.