# In SCALA, How can one construct case class from multiple tuples to handle 22+ fields in json?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using SCALA 2.11 and have a case class with 23 elements which maps to a Json message. But considering that the 23 field limit still exists for functions, I am looking at how to construct this case class for json. This has been very well explained for Tables [here](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2016/10/11/twenty-two.html,) but I am trying to apply this to a json example.

Right now, SCALA throws a compile error for this one. TestJson is a case class which maps to a Json message with 23 fields (it is fixed and the message format is also unchanging).

```
implicit val testJsonReads: Reads[ TestJson ] = (
       (JsPath \ "val1").read[String] and
       :
       :
       :
       (JsPath \ "val23").read[String])(TestJson.apply _)
```

I am trying to break up the 23 values into tuples to avoid the compile error and also apply (for Reads) and unapply  (For writes). How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

[Scala case having 22 fields but having issue with play-json in scala 2.11.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167971/scala-case-having-22-fields-but-having-issue-with-play-json-in-scala-2-11-5)

This answers explains how to do it.

But if I have more than 22 fields in my case class, I prefer to split it into logical groups of case classes.

```
case class GeneralInfo(....)
object GeneralInfo { implicit val format = Json.format[GeneralInfo] }

case class Details(...)
object Details { implicit val format = Json.format[Details] }

case class MyRequest(generalInfo: GeneralInfo, details: Details)
object MyRequest { implicit val format = Json.format[MyRequest] }
```

Comment: Moreover it can be asked if a case class with such much properties at the same level/without structure is a good practice

Comment: @cchantep"..... so much properties at the same level is a good practice" - This has been explained many times. No one does this as a matter of principle but then that is one of the very purposes of the case class - For mapping. It's unreasonable and impractical to ask other teams to impose a field limit on their data (json, DB tables etc.) because our SCALA app cannot handle it.

Comment: That's the purpose of a good mapping to enforce the model rules in the target domain. Even if DB or JSON is "ugly", the mapping is able to model it with nice case classes making sense