# Is there a way to map a JSON object with more then 22 keys in Scala (2.12.4) Play2 (2.6.3)?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Just a simple example, I want to map a JSON response to a Scala case class. I'm using Play2 framework 2.6.3.

```
case class Hobby(id:Int, name:String)
case class Person(name:String,
              name1:String,
              name2:String,
              name3:String,
              name4:String,
              name5:String,
              name6:String,
              name7:String,
              name8:String,
              name9:String,
              name10:String,
              name11:String,
              name12:String,
              name13:String,
              name14:String,
              name15:String,
              name16:String,
              name17:String,
              name18:String,
              name19:String,
              name20:String,
              nickname:Boolean, hobbies:Seq[Hobby], createdDate:LocalDateTime)
```

I know that I could create a reader, Reads[Person] and a Reads[Hobby], or parse manually each field like in this example: https://github.com/playframework/play-json

My question is if I can create a sort of automatic parser using a implicit value, because I have more then 22 fields, and it reaches Scala maximum Tuple22.

JSON example of Person object:

```
    {
  "name": "Mary",
  "name1": "Mary",
  "name2": "Mary",
  "name3": "Mary",
  "name4": "Mary",
  "name5": "Mary",
  "name6": "Mary",
  "name7": "Mary",
  "name8": "Mary",
  "name9": "Mary",
  "name10": "Mary",
  "name11": "Mary",
  "name12": "Mary",
  "name13": "Mary",
  "name14": "Mary",
  "name15": "Mary",
  "name16": "Mary",
  "name17": "Mary",
  "name18": "Mary",
  "name19": "Mary",
  "name20": "Mary",
  "nickname": true,
  "hobbies" : [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "fitness",
      "createdDate": "2018-03-29T17:49:24.5304566+07:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "skating",
      "createdDate": "2018-03-29T17:49:24.5304566+07:00"
    }
  ],
  "createdDate": "2018-03-29T17:49:24.5304566+07:00"
}
```

I managed to reproduce the error that I got, it appears because in the JSON that I was receiving I'm exceeding the Tuple22 in Scala, that is the maximum tuple. This is the error that I was getting:

```
Error:(62, 44) No unapply or unapplySeq function found for class Person: <none> / <none>
      implicit val personReads = Json.reads[Person]
```

Comment: Not clear, give examples

Comment: Yes, you are right. Totally forgot abut an example.

Comment: Still unclear what's the problem

Comment: The problem is that I have to manually parse each field. Coming from Java where you just need annotations to a POJO, this feels like reinventing the wheel. Nvm I found a library, I'll post an answer.

Comment: So, if more then 22 parameters in case class Play JSON library breaks.

Comment: Having more than 22 fields is generally a symptom of a bad design

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala case having 22 fields but having issue with play-json in scala 2.11.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167971/scala-case-having-22-fields-but-having-issue-with-play-json-in-scala-2-11-5)

Comment: I'm wondering why the error message is different then in the possible duplicate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a library that can automatically parse more complex JSONs.

https://circe.github.io/circe/

For LocalDateTime I need to use this:

```
implicit val encodeFoo: Encoder[LocalDateTime] = (a: LocalDateTime) => {
    Json.fromString(a.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME))
}
implicit val decodeFoo: Decoder[LocalDateTime] = (c: HCursor) => {
   c.value.as[String]
    .map(LocalDateTime.parse(_, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME))
}
```

And just use decode method on the JSON string:

```
val person: Person = decode[Person](jsonStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually create the implicit `Reads`/`Writes` objects. Play JSON library handles that.

**Deserialize JSON String to object:**

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Hobby(id:Int, name:String)
case class Person(name:String, nickname:String, hobbies:Seq[Hobby], createdDate:LocalDate)

implicit val hobbyReads = Json.reads[Hobby]
implicit val personReads = Json.reads[Person]

val person: Person = Json.parse(jsonString).as[Person]
```

**Serialize back to JSON String:**

```
implicit val hobbyWrites = Json.writes[Hobby]
implicit val personWrites = Json.writes[Person]

Json.toJson(person).toString()
```

Writing a custom Reads/Writes would only be required if you need to make a custom calculation/manipulation on the input.

Comment: You are right, with my first example your solution works. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

For a 2022 answer: I also had this problem (2.13.6 and playframework 2.8.8) and fixed it using, in some cases, option1, and other cases option2 below. The error that would come up when I had more than 22 fields was:

```
No unapply or unapplySeq function found for class : <none> / <none>
```

Option1: stick to 22 fields or less in your case class. In my code example below, I could introduce new fields (ex: Topic, Requester, Recipient fields) to encapsulate a bunch of fields, thus reducing the number of fields to well below 22.

Option2: if you must have more than 22 fields, you can use the JsonX play extension. See: https://github.com/bizzabo/play-json-extensions

For this, first add the dependency to your **build.sbt**:

```
// to support more than 22 fields in a case class
libraryDependencies += "ai.x" %% "play-json-extensions" % "0.42.0"
```

And then, in your case class, use JsonX, like this:

```
package model

import play.api.libs.json.{Format, Json, OFormat}
import ai.x.play.json.Encoders.encoder
import ai.x.play.json.{BaseNameEncoder, Jsonx, NameEncoder}

case class MyCaseClass(someId: Int,
                              someOtherId: Int,
                              personId: Int,
                              currentStatus: String,
                              currentStatusDesc: String,
                              submittedTimestamp: Long,
                              someCategoryId: Int,
                              someCategoryParentId: Int,
                              someCategoryName: String,
                              someCategoryCode: Int, 
                              topicIsActive: Boolean,
                              topicIsGeneralTopic: Boolean,
                              topicCategorySortOrder: Int,
                              topicIconCssClass: String,
                              recipientPersonId: Option[Int],
                              recipientEmail: Option[String],
                              recipientFirstName: Option[String],
                              recipientLastName: Option[String],
                              recipientExtId: Option[String],
                              requesterSurveyId: Option[Int],
                              requesterSurveyResponse: Option[String],
                              recipientSurveyId: Option[Int],
                              recipientSurveyResponse: Option[String]
                              )
object MyCaseClass{
  // IMPORTANT: because the case class (MyCaseClass) has more than 22 fields, we can't use the default Json.Format
  implicit val f: OFormat[MyCaseClass] = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[MyCaseClass]
}
```

And voilà! You may now transform to JSON more than 22 fields in your case class.