# How to format a case class which its paramters is more than 22

Tags: json, scala, playframework

well,I have looked over the playframework document about [json transformers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonTransformers),it worked well until my case class's parameters more than 22 . When the parameters of case class is more than 22,An error which tell me that the case class's unapplay function couldn't be found has occurred

Comment: did you see http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7910

Comment: 22 is magic barrier in scala , try to avoid use more than that. But if you must, you should group few paramters into another object and embedd it into original one.

Comment: See if this thread can be of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571677/22-fields-limit-in-scala-2-11-play-framework-2-3-case-classes-and-functions/23588132

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have a case class with 22 fields, it is a sign of a incorrect bad. However, if you have no choice to refactor your code you can do the following:

for example here is my case class:

```
case class MyClass(arg1: String, arg2: String, arg3: String)
```

I can rewrite the above class with two fields as follows:

```
case class Helper(arg1: String, arg2: String)
case class MyClass(arg12: Helper, arg3: String)
```

So by factoring out the first two argument in a case class, MyClass will have two fields instead of three. Of course I demonstrated it just by three fields because demonstrating it with 22 fields is tedious ;).